# i am trying to display productname from newproduct mysql table into combobox. The following code is executing but its displaying a blank

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, phpunit

```
**<html>
<body>
<form name="call">
     <select name="category">
<option>Select a category</option>
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("shenvel");
 $category = "SELECT productname FROM newproduct";
 //retrieving product name alone from newproduct
 $query_result = mysql_query($category);
 while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
{
    ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $result['productname']?>"><?php echo $result['productname']?></option>
```

//the above code displays the combo box with one empty space as output.
        
    
    
**

Comment: Where are your `<option>` tags inside the `</select>`? Seems `</select>` is missing.

Comment: Also your are missing `;` after `$result['productname']`.

Answer (score 0):

change fetch records using `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
{
   *********
}
```

And try it..

Comment: "mysql_fetch_assoc() is equivalent to calling mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC for the optional second parameter." from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="category">
<option>Select a category</option>
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("shenvel");
  $category = "SELECT productname FROM newproduct";

  $query_result = mysql_query($category);
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
  {
 ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $result['productname']; ?>"><?php echo $result['productname']; ?></option>  
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: You cannot use the `while (...) { ... }` syntax across multiple `<?php ... ?>` code snippets. If you must use multiple snippets, use the alternate syntax for php while loops `while (...): ... endwhile;`. See php [while()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="call">
     <select name="category">
<option>Select a category</option>
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("shenvel");
 $category = "SELECT productname FROM newproduct";
 //retrieving product name alone from newproduct
 $query_result = mysql_query($category);
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
{
    ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $result['productname']?>"><?php echo $result['productname']?></option>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your while loop is being fully executed in the first `<?php ... ?>` snippet. The syntax you used for your while loop will not execute across multiple php code snippets.

Try echoing out your option HTML code and thus having only one php code snippet.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="call">
<select name="category">
  <option>Select a category</option>
  <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("shenvel");
    $category = "SELECT productname FROM newproduct";
    //retrieving product name alone from newproduct
    $query_result = mysql_query($category);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
      echo '<option value = "',  $result['productname'], '">', $result['productname'], '</option>';
    }
  ?>
```